# AddressSanitizer kills GDB state, even when following Sanitizer Github advice

Tags: c++, gdb, address-sanitizer

I have a double-free bug. I am able to reproduce it using a debug build with Address Sanitizer (AS) detects but when I run under GDB, AS kills the GDB session.

I found this Address Sanitizer page with instructions how to keep GDB:

https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAndDebugger

but when I do:

```
(gdb) break __asan::ReportGenericError
```

at the beginning of the session, the GDB state still disappears after the problem is detected:

```
(gdb) bt
No stack.
```

Comment: It's strange that a user with such a high reputation doesn't provide debugging details, namely the used compiler options.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46580795/6752050. If you use ASAN settings shown there, you will see a bit more than only `CRYPTO_malloc` and `ERR_set_debug`.

Comment: @273K @273K Thank you for that answer. Unfortunately it made no difference. However, the question is how to keep the GDB session active. The call stack doing the initial free (the one you referred to by `ERR_set_debug()`) is instigated by `SSL_connect()`, which is the same function triggering the double free. So somehow the `SSL_connect` call stack eventually frees the same memory. However, each of my SSL objects (one per thread) are independent. The only shared address is that from `TLSv1_2_client_method()` which seems to return the same address each time.

Comment: ASAN doesn't kill a debug session in gdb at me. gdb stops at the point of ASAN dump and `bt` shows a stack call.

Answer (score 0):

> the GDB state still disappears after the problem is detected

There are several possible reasons for this:

1. Somehow you didn't set the breakpoint correctly
2. It's actually a child process that is dying
3. Somehow the thread in which the error is detected is not attached by GDB.

To eliminate 1, use `catch syscall exit_group` (and possibly also `catch syscall exit`) -- this way GDB is sure to stop before the process disappears.

For 2, AddressSanitizer message should indicate the thread id in which the error is detected, and that id should match one of the threads in GDB `info thread` output.

For 3, we'd need to understand more about how that thread was created.